# format float[] to String decimal sign changes to comma

Tags: java, android, string-conversion

### float[] to string

When I try to convert a float array value to a string the sign changes to comma?

```
    private float[] myNum = {0.06f, 0.07f, 0.08f};
```

Case 1:

```
    String myString = String.format("%.2f", myNum[0]);
```

In Case1 myString is "0,06"

Case 2:

```
    String myString = "" + myNum[0];
```

In Case 2 myString is "0.06"

I do not understand why this is happening.
All help is much appreciated.

Comment: Hi Magnus, by any chance you are in EU region and your device language is German or something. Its taking number formating based on the Language you are using.

Comment: What is your Locale set to?

Comment: Hi Kapsym. Yes, I'm in Norway (in the EU region). Ok, thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is because `String.format()` is locale-aware. I'm guessing your default locale is `Locale.GERMAN`, since `Locale.NORWEGIAN` does not exist. And the decimal separator is a comma.

> The locale always used is the one returned by `Locale.getDefault()`.

If you want to format according to a specific locale, then you should use

```
Locale myLocale = ...;
String.format(myLocale, "%.2f", myNum[0]);
```

---

The Java Virtual Machine sets the default locale during startup based on the host environment. It is used by many locale-sensitive methods if no locale is explicitly specified. It can be changed using the `setDefault` method. You can easily check your locale: `System.out.println(Locale.getDefault())`.

Answer (score 0):

`String.format` (case 1) allows you to pass a *locale* which, if not given, will fail over to the default one probably provided by the operating system (the same one as you get if you call `Locale.getDefault()`). That locale is using `,` as the decimal separator.

`String.toString` (which is what case 2 uses, under the hood), never does this - it *always* uses a `.` as the decimal separator.

Java's inconsistent defaulting behaviour is one of its weaknesses.

Answer (score 0):

**Because `String.format(String, Object...)` always applies default Locale, and for your default locale the "," is the decimal separator for floating point numbers**

To not apply locale use the version with `null` Locale:

> ```
>    private float[] myNum = {0.06f, 0.07f, 0,08f};
>    ...
>    String myString = String.format((Locale)null, "%.2f", myNum[0]);
> ```

and the myString is:

```
0.06
```

Comment: Added "decimal" to distinguish from "thousands separator".

Answer (score 0):

The format() method of uses your current Locale while formatting.
My guess is, that your country uses commas instead of decimal points when writing decimal numbers?

Answer (score 0):

As an example a comma would be used as the decimal-point-delimiter if user using Swedish locale, but a dot if it's using an American.

The quoted text above means that the output of String.format will match the default locale the user uses.

If you'd like to force what locale is going to be used, use the overload of String.format that accepts three parameters:

```
String.format (Locale locale, String format, Object... args)
```